# Repurchasing products at a store with a different credit card than the one the order was originally paid with

Tags: united-states, credit-card

I bought some products from Best Buy, Walmart and Frys from their online website that were on sale for a limited time and shipped them to store last week.

The credit card that I used to pay the order with used to offer a year of extended warranty but does not anymore (and I forgot that).

I do have other cards that still offer this feature and would like to "repurchase" the items using the other cards so that I can get the extended warranty.

Is there a way I could pickup the items in store and pay the price (not the current price of the items which is higher) that I originally paid?

Comment: Fry's doesn't actually charge the card on the website if store pickup is selected. They do so when the item is actually picked up. So use the card you want when you go for the pickup. You might still have to show the card that you used online but you can use any card to pay.

Answer (score 1):

If the price has changed then probably not. You would basically need to return the item and buy it again. That means you'd pay the current price. Also, not everything you can buy on-line can be purchased in-store, even if you have just returned that exact item. I had this problem with Fry's once.